# Tensor derivatives

Tags: matrix-calculus

Refer http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html Page 207

> Usually we do not apply the back-propagation algorithm merely to
>   vectors, but rather to tensors of arbitrary dimensionality.
>   Conceptually, this is exactly the same as back-propagation with
>   vectors. The only difference is how the numbers are arranged in a grid
>   to form a tensor. We could imagine flattening each tensor into a
>   vector before we run back-propagation, computing a vector-valued
>   gradient, and then reshaping the gradient back into a tensor. In this
>   rearranged view, back-propagation is still just multiplying Jacobians
>   by gradients.

I don't understand the above statement from a book.

1. What does it mean by flattening each tensor to a vector, why would you do that? What is a tensor here,- a vector, matrix or more than 2 dimensions, and how does that affect the process of flattening?
2. What does the last statement mean?

Comment: Which book? $\phantom{}$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown added the book and page.

Comment: What book?  What context?  "back-propagation algorithm" sounds 'computer-ish'.  I would hope some of the terms are defined in the book.  "Flattening a tensor into a vector" might be a generalization of the process of placing each row of a matrix in the same ordered $nm-$tuple.  So the $3\times3$ matrix is {{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}, then the flattened version is the 3x3-tuple  {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i}.  Sorry, I am posting from my phone so I'm not using good notation.